# JQuery: calling a script inline vs externally

Tags: jquery

Only some pages require the textarea.js script so I only want to call it on pages that need it. This is how I'm calling it now (I link to the external file textarea.js and then I call it with inline code at the end of the HTML file):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/external.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/textarea.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('textarea').autoGrowTextArea();
        });
</script>

</html>
```

**Would it be good practice to remove the call at the end of the HTML file and instead place it at the tail end of the external textarea.js file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I would include the resource as you are, and bootstrap your resources as you are. You might want to create a single `init()` function which does the bootstrapping though. The main benefit of abstracting the bootstrap is that you can put it inside a custom hook or callback and defer the `autoGrowTextArea()` logic until after any dependencies are ready.

As an aside, you can shorten this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

to this:

```
$(function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an expected aspect of the library then **yes**, it should be inside of the external .js file. The only reason you wouldn't do that is if your library does not have a constraint on jquery (which it seems to as you have invoked an extension).

jQuery's own library for validation uses a very similar line of code, in which it adds a call to the validation api to `document.ready`.